# How do I mark a cell if another cell contains data from a list in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a spreadsheet and I need to have a way to mark items that have been recently ordered.

Each row is an item in inventory. I have a separate list of item numbers that have been recently ordered.

I need a function that will look to see if the item number for each row (column A) is also present in my list (Column A on another sheet, "Recent POs") and flag those rows accordingly, perhaps by returning a message such as (recently ordered).

I've tried a handful of things and am struggling. This seems like it should be easy.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple CountIF() of the items ordered, nested in an IF() statement. If the count is zero, the "False" part of the IF() statement will be executed. If the count is greater than zero, the "True" part of the IF() will be executed, since any value other than 0 is equal to TRUE. So, in your first sheet, enter this into row 2 and copy down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Recent POs'!A:A,A2),"recently ordered","")
```

For an example see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for exact matches, the [MATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb239415%28v=office.12%29.aspx) function will probably be sufficient for this. If the item number you want to check is in `A1` and the list of recently ordered items is in `E1:E9` on the `Recent POs` sheet, you can enter this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,'Recent POs'!$E$1:$E$9,0)),"","Recently ordered")
```

This will return blank for items not recently ordered and show "Recently ordered" for those that were. You can fill this formula down the column to generate flags for the entire item list.